# Converting from sqlite database column (char*) to NSPropertyList?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos

I have the following chunk of code which I am using to deserialize some data that's stored in an sqlite3 database which was recovered from an iphone address book utility.

```
if (strcmp(azColName[i], "ZADDRESSES") == 0) {
    NSData *data;
    NSString *error;
    data = [NSData dataWithBytes:argv[i] length:strlen(argv[i])];
    NSPropertyListFormat format;

    NSMutableArray *emails  = [NSPropertyListSerialization 
                                propertyListFromData:data
                                mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable 
                                format:&format 
                                errorDescription:&error];

    NSString *content = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

azColName[i] is from a sqllite database (char*). This code is part of the DB callback. Upon inspection, it seems to be a plist of some kind:

```
2012-03-05 00:57:22.467 exporter[20488:707] ZADDRESSES = bplist00‘JKT$topX$objectsX$versionY$archiver—Troot .. and so on ...
```

Unfortunately, this conversion always fails. Error gets populated with "Conversion of string failed. The string is empty."

The data object has no problem, but deserialization fails. Why does it think the string is blank here?